# using mysql and php with google maps

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, google-maps

I'm trying loop through every row in a table and set a marker using the value provided in the "address column". The js code and the php code until  setMarker() works fine but I'm not sure how to go about using the function inside php code.

```
<?php
require 'private/database.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM form;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<script>setMarker($row["address"]);</script>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<script>console.log("ERROR: marker database empty");</script>';
}
```

```
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 15,
  center: {lat: 24.149950, lng: 120.638610},
  mapId: '63d22d3ae6cf15ff'
  });
}


// geocoder
function setMarker(address) {
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({address: address, componentRestrictions: {
    country: 'TW'}}, (results, status) => {
    if (status === 'OK') {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
    } else {
        alert(`Geocode unsuccessful for address: "${address}"\nSTATUS CODE: ${status}`);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: `echo "<script>setMarker({$row['address']});</script>';` You missed the `$` on the PHP variable name

Comment: generate an array or json object in javascript and process that in the `initMap` callback

Comment: Perhaps I didn't word that very well - I meant to use PHP to generate a Javascript array(json object) and then call that from within the callback rather than calling the setMarker function as you are here

Comment: Have you seen Google's tutorial/sample: [Using MySQL and PHP with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps)

Comment: Or even better, use AJAX to get the values from your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less what I meant with the comment I made - this way the map is created by the `initMap` callback function before any attempts to create the markers is made - which might not be the case in the original. This is quickly put together and not tested.

```
<script>
    var map;
    <?php


        require 'private/database.php';

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM form;";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $data=array();


        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $data[]=$row;
        }
        // create the js variable
        printf(
            'var json=%s;',
            json_encode( $data )
        );
    ?>

    
    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: {lat: 24.149950, lng: 120.638610},
          mapId: '63d22d3ae6cf15ff'
      });
      Object.keys(json).forEach( key => {
        let obj=json[ key ];
        setMarker( obj['address'] )
      })
    }



    function setMarker(address) {
        const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { address: address, componentRestrictions: { country: 'TW'} }, (results, status) => {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert(`Geocode unsuccessful for address: "${address}"\nSTATUS CODE: ${status}`);
            }
        });
    }
    
</script>
```